# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'onesignal_client'

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, onesignal

I'm setting up my Django Rest API on Linux instance-template-1 5.10.0-14-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.113-1 (2022-04-29) x86_64

Python 3.9 is installed and Django 4x

I've installed One signal required by my API using

- sudo pip3 install onesignal
- sudo pip3 install onesignal_sdk

The module not found error throws up when I run

- sudo python3.9 manage.py migrate

The detailed error trace is as follows :

```html
File "/home/lineofsight/myprojects/my API/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 304, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  
File "/home/lineofsight/myprojects/My API/myapp_auth/models.py", line 25, in <module>
    from myapp_notifications.helpers import get_notification_language_code_for_target_user
  
File "/home/lineofsight/myprojects/My API/myapp_notifications/helpers.py", line 4, in <module>
    import onesignal as onesignal_sdk
  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/onesignal/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from onesignal_client import OneSignal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'onesignal_client'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't install the correct python location.
Please try to install using the following commands.

```
python3.9 -m pip install onesignal
python3.9 -m pip install onesignal_sdk
```

Comment: Tried the above. Didn't work. its says "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable. Requirement already satisfied

Comment: I installed onesignal-client. Now the error is  - AttributeError: module 'onesignal' has no attribute 'Client'